# Grails 2.3.9 & Spock: How do mock the returns of "where" queries?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, spock

Suppose I have this where query:

```
MyModel.where {
            group == 'someGroup' && owner {association == association}
}.list()
```

How do I mock it in my test? I tried doing something like this:

```
MyModel.metaClass.where = {
       return [myModel1, myModel2]
}
```

But, it didn't work. So, I tried doing this:

```
def myModelMock = Mock(MyModel)
myModelMock.where(_) >> [myModel1, myModel2]
```

and it still didn't work. What other ways can I mock that query? I just want it to return a list. :(

Comment: How about moving that query to a method and then mocking that method to return a list?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things wrong with the metaClass approach that you tried.  The `where` method is static so instead of this:

```
MyModel.metaClass.where = {
   return [myModel1, myModel2]
}
```

Use something like this:

```
MyModel.metaClass.static.where = {
   return [myModel1, myModel2]
}
```

Another thing that is wrong with that is you have the `where` method returning a `List` of `MyModel` instances.  Instead, you want to return some object that will respond to the `list()` method and that should return a `List` of `MyModel.  Something like this...

```
MyModel.metaClass.static.where = { Closure crit ->
    // List of instances...
    def instances = [myModel1, myModel2]

    // a Map that supports .list() to return the instances above
    [list: {instances}]
}
```

I hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

I think the code above addresses the question as asked but I should mention that a more common thing to do is to use the `mockDomain` method to provide mock instances:

```
// grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy
package demo

class DemoController {

    def index() {
        def results = MyModel.where {
            group == 'jeffrey'
        }.list()

        [results: results]
    }
}
```

Then in a test...

```
// test/unit/demo/DemoControllerSpec.groovy
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(DemoController)
@Mock(MyModel)
class DemoControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "this is just an example"() {
        setup:
        mockDomain(MyModel, [new MyModel(group: 'jeffrey'), new MyModel(group: 'not jeffrey')])

        when:
        def model = controller.index()

        then:
        // make whatever assertions you need
        // make sure you really are testing something
        // in your app and not just testing that 
        // the where method returns what it is supposed
        // to.  
        model.results.size() == 1
    }
}
```